# write multiple files in C iterating over their names

Tags: c, string, for-loop, printf

I am trying to write a bunch of files by iterating, doing some calculations and adding the index to the file's name, heres part of my code (I emphasized where the code stops compiling):

```
float AltAzCalc(int d, float t, float Lon, float RA, float Dec, float Lat){

    FILE *in;


    -----> char filename[30] = ("hiparcos_horizontal_%lf_%lf.csv",Lon,Lat);
    in = fopen(filename, "w");
    float PI = 3.14159265;// pi
    float G = 6.5949997; 
    float Alt , Az;
    float GST = G + 0.0657098244*d + 1.00273791*t;
    if (GST > 24){
        GST = GST - 24;
    }
    float LST = GST*360/24 + Lon;

    Alt = (180/PI)*(asin(sin(PI*Dec/180)*sin(PI*Lat/180) + cos(PI*Dec/180)*cos(PI*Lat/180)*cos(PI*(LST-RA*360/24)/180)));

    if(sin(PI*(LST-RA*360/24)/180) <= 0){
        Az = (180/PI)*(acos((sin(PI*Dec/180)-(sin(PI*Alt/180)*sin(PI*Lat/180)))/(cos(PI*Alt/180)*cos(PI*Lat/180))));
    }else{
        Az = 360 - (180/PI)*(acos((sin(PI*Dec/180)-(sin(PI*Alt/180)*sin(PI*Lat/180)))/(cos(PI*Alt/180)*cos(PI*Lat/180))));
    }   

    fprintf(in," %lf %lf \n",Alt,Az);

}
int main{
for(int i = -180 ; i < 181 ; i++){
        for(int j = -180 ; j < 181 ; j++){ 
            for(int k = 0; k < 119616 ; k++){

                AltAzCalc(97,9.2,i,AscensionRecta.array[k],Declinacion.array[k],j);



            }

         }
    }
}
```

I have used such syntaxes before only not adding any extra numbers that I want to change, which is a string literal and that's what its asking for, any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Looks like you need the help of `sprintf()`.

Comment: Could you please provide a simple expample of its sintaxis?

Comment: Maybe you've trimmed your code for simplicity, but you *must* check for errors when opening a file.  `in = fopen(filename,"w"); if(in == NULL) {perror(filename); ... }`

Comment: @WilliamPursell Why? (i'm starting to learn C)

Comment: If the fopen fails (eg, the file exists and you don't have write permission) and you don't check, the program will segfault.  When the user sees `Segmentation fault` as an error message, is far less useful than `hiparcos_horizontal_1_1.csv: permission denied`

Comment: @CarlosSanchez Please do not add _solved_ kind of message in the question body. The acceptance mark does it all. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two major things:

1. `char filename[30]` is probably too small in dimension to hold the name.
2. You need to use [`sprintf()`/`snprintf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf) to generate the filename.

Worthy to mention, `%f` is enough and recommended to print a float value.

Do something like (pseudo-code)

```
char filename[128] = {0};                                   //allocate enough memory
sprintf(filename, "hiparcos_horizontal_%f_%f.csv",Lon,Lat)); //Added missing semi-colon // use %f, that's enough and recommended, too.
```

Note: Always check the return value of `fopen()` for success before using the returned file pointer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a formatted string, use [snprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/):

```
char filename[30];

snprintf(filename, sizeof filename, "hiparcos_horizontal_%f_%f.csv", Lon, Lat);
```

And `%f` instead of `%lf` to print a `float`.

Also note (as pointed out by @SouravGhosh) that `[30]` is too small to hild the entire filename.

Comment: Sir, isn't `[30]` too small to hold the _entire_ filename?

Comment: @CarlosSanchez Once you generate the filename properly, it __will__ become the _biggest_ issue. YMMV.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I'm getting scared Sourav, because i ***know for a fact*** that the data this codes generate is way more than what my computer can take and i'm not as good at handling pointers

Answer (score 1):

What you have here it a comma-expression enclosed in parentheses. It contains three subexpressions—a string and two `float` variables—which are 'calculated' in odrer from left to right, then the result of the last subexpression becomes the result of the whole paren. Thus a result (value in this case) of a string and `Lon` variable remain unused, as compiler said. Then the result of `Lat` is inappropriate to initialize a `char` array.

The compiler has no idea you want a formatted string, you need to write it explicitly, as others said: first you need to prepare a buffer long enough for your file name:

```
char filename[66];
```

then fill it with data:

```
sprintf(filename, "hiparcos_horizontal_%lf_%lf.csv", Lon, Lat);
```

The formatting string itself contains 25 plain characters. Assuming both `Lon` and `Lat` will convert to no more than 20 characters each (but verify that with the `sprintf` description!) the total file name should not exceed 65 characters. Add one for the NUL terminator and you have the size of 66 in a declaration.

Oh, and don't forget to `fclose` a file once you finished writing to it!